# C++: Using a Template for a Constructor

Tags: c++, class, templates

Is it possible to use a template on a constructor, for example:

```cpp
class Class {
    public:
        template<typename T>
        Class(T arg);
};
```

And the cpp file:

```cpp
#include "class.h"

template<typename T>
Class::Class (T arg) {
    // do something
}
```

The constructor is called with:

```cpp
int a = 0;
Class c {a};
```

---

When compiling this code, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccNzp4z7.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `Class::Class<int>(int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

The use for this would be a constructor like:

```cpp
Class(std::unordered_set<T> choices, std::unordered_map<Direction, std::function<std::string(T)>> mapping);
```

Where each object in `choices` would be iterated over for each `Direction` in the map and passed to the corresponding function, in order to generate the object. In this case, the type used has no bearing on the class after the constructor finished executing, so I don't think that it makes sense to use a template on the entire class.

Comment: Yes, a constructor can be a template.

Comment: What happens when you try compiling, and running this?

Comment: If `choices` and `mapping` are member variables then you'll need to template the `class` and not just the `ctor`.

Comment: I added the error the the question, I probably should have included it

Comment: They are not member variables, the list of choices is simply looped through in various ways and passes to the one of the functions, which always return a string. The string is the only part saved in the class.

Comment: Where is your `constructor` defined? In the `.cpp` file?

Comment: Something to keep in mind when dealing with templates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/

Comment: Yes, it is defined in the cpp file

Comment: @RemyLebeau So the constructor must be inline in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you've defined your `ctor` in the `.cpp` file. You must define your `template` in the header.

```
// class.hpp

class Class
{
public:
     template<typename T>
     Class( T arg )
     {
         // Define the ctor body here.
     }
};
```

Comment: What does the explicit qualifier do in this case?

Comment: It stops the `ctor` from implicitly converting types. It's good practice but not necessary. You can remove it if you'd prefer.

Comment: Can you give an example of when this would be problematic? Also, when would you use explicit in general? I've never really used it.

Comment: I'm going to direct you to another thread for that question. There are good examples explaining what issue `explicit` fixes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-mean

Comment: Did defining the `constructor` body in the `header` fix your issue?